# Having trouble understanding .this keyword use in this code

Tags: java

Please explain the code, unable to understand what test(3).x means in the main method

```
class Test { 
     int x=0; 
     static int y=1;
     Test(){  
      this.y++;
      this.x+=++x;  
      }

    Test(int x){   
      this();
      System.out.println(x+this.x+this.y);
      }
    }


    public class MyClass {
       public static void main(String args[]) {
         System.out.println(new Test(3).x+" "+new Test(4).y);
    }

}
```

Comment: Format your code properly if you want people to help you. And realise the clause is `new Test(3).x` NOT `test(3).x` which would be something different

Comment: The `+` is the code you ask for is just for string concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Test(3).x` can be rewritten in this form:

```
Test myObject = new Test(3);
myObject.x
```

which you might be more familiar with.

All it does is create a `Test` object and access that object's `x` field.

The program prints

```
6
8
1 3
```

The first constructor call makes `y` be 2, and `this.x` be 1. `x+this.x+this.y`, which is 3+1+2=6, is then printed. The second constructor call makes `y` be 3, and `this.x` be 1. `x+this.x+this.y`, which is 4+1+3=8, is then printed.

Now the whole expression `new Test(3).x+" "+new Test(4).y` is evaluated. `new Test(3).x` is 1, and `Test.y` is 3. These two values are then printed.

Answer (score 0):

`Test(3)` here means that you are calling the parametrised constructor `Test(int x)` and passing the value of 3 to x. `this` keyword is used to refer to the current object of the class. When you use this.variable name, it means you are referring to the variable associated with the current object in scope in the class (You are creating a new object using the "new" keyword, Eg. `new Test(3).x` ). Thereby, the parametrised constructor will accordingly be invoked, and whatever code is there within it will be resolved accordingly by the compiler.